# Why does "in" keyword not work as expected in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a currency converter and I am trying to see if the currency the user enters is in the currency list that I have, even though it is in there, the program prints false.

```
const currencies = {
  "JPY": 113.5,
  "EUR": 0.89,
  "RUB": 74.36,
  "GBP":0.75,
  "USD":1
}
currencyNames = Object.keys(currencies);
console.log("JPY" in currencyNames);  // false
```

Comment: `in` will check for the index, because its an array not an object, use `console.log(currencyNames.includes("JPY"));` instead

Comment: Because it tests property _names_, not values. `"JPY" in currencies` would work.

Comment: Stack overflow should not be your first stop when you find something you didn't expect. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) should be.

Comment: *Why does "in" keyword not work as expected in JavaScript* Well obviously the expectations were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The `in` [operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) works with objects and **not** with arrays.

Knowing this, we can fix the code snippet you provided by using the `in` operator on the currencies object.

```
const currencies = {
  "JPY": 113.5,
  "EUR": 0.89,
  "RUB": 74.36,
  "GBP":0.75,
  "USD":1
}
console.log("JPY" in currencies ); // true
```

Comment: The `in` operator works just fine with arrays, which are _also_ objects.